# Array that is consoled.log is not updating javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, callback

My array numbers are not updating when they are squared. I'm not familiar with callbacks and how to get their values to update the array. The foreach function runs the callback on each element of the array (updates the array passed in). forEach does not return anything.

```js
//This function is to square a desired number
const square = a => (a*a)
//this function 
function map(array, callback) {
    const arrNew= [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrNew.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
    return arrNew;
}

function forEach(array, callback) {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1) {
      callback(array[i]);
      newArray.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
}
var myarray = [10,20];
forEach(myarray, square);
// this should log 100,400 but is instead doing 10,20
console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: `forEach` simply iterates the elements of the array. If you don't make any assignments inside the loop, nothing outside it will change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `newArray` in `forEach`

```js
//This function is to square a desired number
const square = a => (a*a)

function forEach(array, callback) {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1) {
      newArray.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
   return newArray
}
var myarray = [10,20];
myarray = forEach(myarray, square);
// this should log 100,400 but is instead doing 10,20
console.log(myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this example you can use the below code.

```
const myArray = [10, 20];

const squaredArray = myArray.map((item) => item * item);

console.log(squaredArray);
```

You can use map when do you want access de all items in your array and return one value. The "forEach" you access also your array, but the "forEach" can't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over complicating this process. To get your desired result you can simply use the map function. For example:

```
var myarray = [10,20]

console.log(myarray.map((number) => number * number))
```

If you run this code you will get `[100,400]` logged in the console.

What is happening here is that we are calling the map method on the array. This method is taking a callback function. The callback function is this part

```
(number) => number * number)
```

So what is happening here? The map method is iterating over the provided array, and for each element, it is running that function, then returns the results in a new array.

I would suggest watching some videos and reading more about higher-order functions (which .map is one example of)

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkWxvB1RJq0&t=831s) helped me alot when I was first learning about them
.